# What is the equivalent of creating MySQL indexes in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

As you probably know, in MySQL you can create indexes to improve the performance of your queries. Is there any such equivalent in Elastic? (I already know that an index is somewhat the equivalent of creating a database in Elastic)

I just need confirmation from  black-belt Elastic users ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_indexing_employee_documents.html):

> Relational databases add an index, such as a B-tree index, to specific
>   columns in order to improve the speed of data retrieval. Elasticsearch
>   and Lucene use a structure called an inverted index for exactly the
>   same purpose.
>
> By default, every field in a document is indexed (has an inverted index) and thus is searchable. A field without an inverted index is
>   not searchable. We discuss inverted indexes in more detail in [Inverted
>   Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html).